# Apache James Server set message id

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, james

I configured Apache James Server 3.0-beta4 and I am able to send/receive e-mails. The problem that rises is that I need to be able to change the id of a message on the server. I can see the ids of all the messages, but I cannot set them manually. I have an application that will use the e-mails in their raw format, and I want to be able to set their ids manually. Is there any way in which I could do that?

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you want to take in messages with arbitrary Message-ID headers, and then change the Message-ID when the message arrives on the server?

Comment: @BillShannon - Yes, that is what I want to do.